# String is empty but ModelState is still valid with various annotations to make it invalid

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, .net-core, modelstate

Using .NET core 2.1 I tried various DataAnnotations on my Model but everything's still valid when my Title property is an empty string. I tried them all independently from each other as well...

```
public class TestDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
    [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "200 Characters is the maximum allowed for requirements.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromBody] List<TestDto> testModelList)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (TestDto testModel in testModelList)
        {
            //do things
            return Ok();
        }
    }else{
        return BadRequest("ModelState invalid");
    }
}
```

I even tried creating an own annotation for my "Title" property:

```
public class EnsureNotEmptyAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var stringToTest = value as String;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToTest))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which didn't work either. What can possibly cause that? It's simply ignoring my annotations. When Title is null, the ModelState is invalid, but I need the ModelState to be invalid for empty strings too.

Comment: How are you rending the model in the View? There is a difference between validating single model Item and list of model items individually.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Im using angular 5/6. Here is the part in my code that posts to  my .NET core project: https://pastebin.com/px6uZeZc btw I changed my variable names because it's private project I can't show too much of

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the modelstate applies to a collection of your models. Can you try this.
Pseudocode:

```
 if (testModelList.Any(model => !TryValidateModel(model)))
 {   
     return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
 }
```

Comment: Same result. Model's still valid.

Comment: Even if you remove all annotations and add your own custom Annotation 'EnsureNotEmptyAttribute '. What do you see when you iterate over every model.

Does your method getting hit, and what is the result from the TryValidateModel of this model.

Comment: my annotation doesnt get fired and testModelList.Any(model => !TryValidateModel(model)) is false which means TryValidateModel(model) returns true

Comment: I always tested with one single item and I also rearranged my code so that it accepts one single TestDto Object as the parameter and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that in my startup.cs I was adding MvcCore and not Mvc in general. The difference is described [here](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/07/difference-between-addmvc-addmvcore/). I simply had to add DataAnnotations and it finally worked.